# Java - is mixed type container (non-generic class) possible without unchecked cast?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, unchecked

I am trying to make a simple storage class, that will store different classes instances. The only almost correct way I managed to do is with unchecked type casting.

```
HashSet<T> result = (HashSet<T>) storage.get(s);
```

Can it be done without unchecked casting and without making the class generic (`class Storage<T> { }`)?

```
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.*;

class Tests {
    @Test
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Storage storage = new Storage();

        HashSet<Child1> child1Set = storage.get("child1");
        HashSet<Child1> duplicateChild1Set = storage.get("child1");

        Assert.assertNotNull(child1Set);
        Assert.assertSame(child1Set, duplicateChild1Set);

        HashSet<Child2> child2Set = storage.get("child2");

        Assert.assertNotNull(child2Set);
        Assert.assertNotSame(child1Set, child2Set);
    }
}

class Storage {

    public Map<String, HashSet<? extends Parent>> storage = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends Parent> HashSet<T> get(String s) {
        HashSet<T> result = (HashSet<T>) storage.get(s);
        if (result == null) {
            result = new HashSet<>();
            storage.put(s, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Parent { }

class Child1 extends Parent { }

class Child2 extends Parent { }
```

Comment: That unchecked type cast is safe, and you shouldn't be worried about it. You can even suppress is - `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Unfortunately, that's the way you've to create a Heterogenous type safe containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `Class` objects as keys, rather than `String`s. Here is a short example. For simplicity, I have not included `extends Parent` - you can put those back.

```
public final class Storage {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Set<?>> storage = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> Set<T> get(Class<T> s) {
        Set<T> result = (Set<T>) storage.get(s); // Unchecked cast
        if (result == null) {
            result = new HashSet<>();
            storage.put(s, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It is not possible to eliminate the unchecked cast in a mixed type container like this. There is no way to specify that if the key has type `Class<T>`, the value has type `Set<T>`. However, as long as the user of the `Storage` class does not ignore any type safety warnings, this is completely type safe.

To use the class you can do `storage.get(Double.class).add(4.2);`, for example.

Comment: You said "It is not possible to eliminate the unchecked cast" which is a wrong argument to answer the question

Comment: @HeyStackExchange You've missed the entire point of the question. The whole idea is that `Storage` is a mixed type container. The OP even explicitly says `without making the class generic (class Storage<T>`

Comment: Can't upvote you dude. "You last voted on this answer 13 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"